# Qt4 include file prevent emacs semantic or auto complete from working?

Tags: emacs, qt4, elisp, emacs23, qt4.8

I spent many hours to configure and test emacs semantic and auto complete for Qt4.
I found that these CANNOT even parse or find the Qt4 include file because of the indirectly include.
For example, QString> include qstring.h (include ../../src/tools/qstring.h, mingw)
I always get "Wrong type argument: stringp, nil" (Try on Linux or Mingw)
I don't know Lisp.  CAN YOU HELP ME OUT WITH IT? 
THANKS VERY MUCH!

Debug trace as below:

```
 Debugger entered--Lisp error: (wrong-type-argument stringp nil)
  call-process(nil nil #<buffer *clang-output*> nil "-cc1" "-fsyntax-only" "-I~/project/qt481-mingw/include" "-I~/project/qt481-mingw/include/Qt" "-I~/project/qt481-mingw/include/QtCore" "-I~/project/qt481-mingw/include/QtGui" "-code-completion-at" "c:/Users/ygao/project/tests/test-qt-semantic.cpp:13:8" "c:/Users/ygao/project/tests/test-qt-semantic.cpp")

  apply(call-process nil nil #<buffer *clang-output*> nil ("-cc1" "-fsyntax-only" "-I~/project/qt481-mingw/include" "-I~/project/qt481-mingw/include/Qt" "-I~/project/qt481-mingw/include/QtCore" "-I~/project/qt481-mingw/include/QtGui" "-code-completion-at" "c:/Users/ygao/project/tests/test-qt-semantic.cpp:13:8" "c:/Users/ygao/project/tests/test-qt-semantic.cpp"))

  (if ac-clang-auto-save (apply (quote call-process) ac-clang-executable nil buf nil args) (apply (quote call-process-region) (point-min) (point-max) ac-clang-executable nil buf nil args))
```

Answer (score 1):

From the stack trace, it seems like `ac-clang-executable` is nil. Try `M-x customize-option RET ac-clang-executable` and set it to the path to your `clang` binary.